# Laravel Forge: How to stop queue workers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I have configured a queue worker as a daemon on Forge, then used the recommended deployment script command (`php artisan queue:restart`).

How do I manually stop and restart the queue worker?  If I stop it, supervisor will just restart it.  Do I need kill the active worker in Forge first?

This may be required on an ad-hoc basis.  For example, if I want to clear a log file that the queue has open.

Comment: `supervisorctl stop <name of task>`?

Answer (score 3):

I've been pretty vocal in deployment discussions, and I always tell people to stop their worker processes with the supervisorctl command.

```
supervisorctl stop <name of task>
```

Using the `queue:restart` command doesn't actually restart anything. It sets an entry in the cache which the worker processes check, and shutdown. As you noticed, supervisor will then restart the process.

This means that `queue:restart` has one huge problem, ignoring the naming and the fact that it doesn't restart; it will cause all worker processes on all servers that uses the same cache to restart. I think this is wrong, I think a deployment should only affect the current server currently being deployed to.

If you're using a per-server cache, like the `file` cache driver, then this has another problem; what happens if your deployment entirely removes the website folder? The cache would change, the queues would start again, and the worker process may have a mix of old and new code. Fun things to debug...

Supervisor will signal the process when it is shutting down, and wait for it to shut down cleanly, and if it doesn't, forcefully kill it. These timeouts can be configured in the supervisor configuration file. This means that using supervisorctl to stop the queue process will not terminate any jobs "half-way through", they will all complete (assuming they run for a short enough time, or you increase the timeouts).

Comment: Woah, I'd never considered the `queue:restart` thing with multiple servers before. Great point.

Comment: How you find out the name of task in the supervisorctl?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas You specify the task name in your configuration file. In the documentation the `[program:laravel-worker]` will create the name `laravel-worker` which is later used when invoking supervisorctl. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: I think you can send the individual workers a `SIGSTOP` and they will catch that and handle it in the same way as the `queue:restart`. If you can identify the processes of the workers you want to restart, send them that signal for a clean restart when they have finished processing their current job. There are some conditions where that may not work, but it can be tried.

Comment: @Jason You are probably thinking of SIGTERM. It still has some of the problems of queue:restart; it just shuts down and expects a process manager to restart it. You would need to use the process manager's commands to ensure it is stopped during the deployment, and isn't started again until after the deployment is finished.